# understanding algorithmic complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm looking at some online algorithm solutions for coding interviews, and I don't understand why this algorithm is claimed to be O(n^3).

> Caveat: I understand that big-Oh notation is abused in industry, and when I refer to O(n), I'm using that notation to mean the upper bound of an algorithms runtime as is common outside of academia in most places.

Finding the longest palindromic substring. A simple solution might be:

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string s) {
  if (s.length() <= 1) {
    return true;
  }

  if (s[0] == s[s.length() - 1]) {
    return isPalindrome(s.substr(1, s.length() - 2));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

std::string longestPalindrome(std::string s) {
  std::string max_pal = "";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    for (size_t len = 1; len <= s.length() - i; ++len) {
      std::string sub = s.substr(i,len);
      if (isPalindrome(sub)) {
        if (max_pal.size() < sub.size()) max_pal = sub;
      }
    }
  }
  return max_pal;
}
```

Isn't this algorithm O(n^2)? Very simply, it takes O(n^2) time to generate all substrings, and O(n) time to determine if it's a palindrome. Where n is the number of characters in the initial string.

Comment: I wonder if it counting creating substrings as part of the complexity.

Comment: it takes O(n^2) time to generate all substrings, and O(n) to check **each one**

Comment: I know this wasn't the question, but here's a quick idea for an O(n^2) algorithm, for completeness' sake: There is only a linear number of possible "center points", and it takes at most a linear amount of time to count the length of each candidate by expanding it from the middle. There are palin. of even and odd length though, e.g. ABBA vs. BOB. For the former, we pick a center that is "between" two characters. Probably best to also start with a center point in the middle of the string. For inputs that contain the same character many times, this gets complexity down to O(n).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't this algorithm O(n^2)? Very simply, it takes O(n^2) time to
>   generate all substrings, and O(n) time to determine if it's a
>   palindrome.

What you are describing is exactly `O(n^3)`, because for each substring, you are doing an operation which costs `O(n)`, so total number of operations is `O(n^2 * C*n)`, which is `O(n^3)`

---

**However**, the code described is actually `O(n^4)`, `isPalindrome()` is `O(n^2)`:

- You are creating `O(n)` substrings, of sizes: `1 + 3 + 5 + ... + n-2`, which is `O(n^2)` total time.
- Doing this `O(n^2)` times in `longestPalindrome()` totals to `O(n^4)`.

(This assumes `O(n)` `substr()` complexity. It's not defined - but [it's usually the case](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/))

Comment: why is isPalindrome O(n^2)? Doesn't it check each character of the string exactly once?

Comment: @JohnDoe Since string::substr() is `O(n)`, and you are doing it recursively along the way `O(n)` times. Total size of substrings created is `1 + 3 + 5 + ... + n-2`, which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Captain Obvious here… In C++17, a simple efficiency fix would be to change the parameter type of `isPalindrome` to `std::string_view`, whose `substr` has constant complexity. I'm pretty sure the whole problem could be solved with a O(n^2) worst case algorithm, though…

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right,
it takes O(n^2) and O(n) operations to generate the strings and check them.
Thus, you need O(n^2) (amount of strings) times O(n) checks.
Since n^2 * n = n^3, the total run time is in O(n^3).

Answer (score 1):

O(n^2) (substring turns out to be O(n) itself) is executed inside double loop (O(n^2)). That gives us O(n^4).

Comment: That implementaiton is actually O(n^4).

Comment: Waaat? How? String.substring is O(1), how you've got O(n^4)?

Comment: From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) `Complexity: Unspecified, but generally linear in the length of the returned object.` I am pretty sure in C++11 it must be linear, since COW is no longer a thing, but I am not going to commit on that.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I've been sure that it reuses somehow underlying array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this'd be even O(N^4), because of the barbarity of the implementation.

`isPalindrome` is implemented in such a way, that for every recursive invocation it **allocates** a new string, which is essentially the source string with first and last chars removed. So every such a call is already O(n).

Comment: I will have you know, sir, that I know some very talented barbarians. No one executes a divide and conquer algorithm like my old friend Tuborg the Barbarian. Assuming he's sober, that is. Drinks a lot.